# Custom animation for the Keyboard when an EditText is getting focus?

Tags: android, animation, android-softkeyboard

Is there a way to change the keyboard's incoming effect, when an EditText is getting focus?

Let's say, for example, make an alpha animation for the keyboard??

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way you can do that is by making your own keyboard but I think this way you will have to develop two different apps, one for the keyboard and your original app and I don't think you want that. So I think you can't do that.

Comment: Cata is right. It's unpossible to change the keyboard behavior.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'll stick to the original keyboard :D

Answer (score 0):

There are custom ROMs built that allow that. My ROM builder for my galaxy s2 is AOKP and they added 12 custom keyboard animations and 13 custom windows transitions. See what groups build for your device, backup your stuff, jailbreak, root, and load new ROM. Hope this helps.

Comment: If one builds application for many Android phones, he wants to able to support as more devices as possible. Supporting only a few devices with a specific android ROM is a bad idea.